# How to import Microsoft Exchange data to SQL in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, exchange-server

My boss gave me a job to rewrite an old piece of software into a SSIS package. I need the SSIS to:

- access a specific mailbox on our Microsoft Exchange server
- go through all the UNREAD emails and download attachments from them based on their file type
- import the contents of these files (text readable through notepad) into an SQL table
- import email subjects to another SQL table

I'm not sure if what I described above is available in a standard SSIS package (I doubt it) - maybe I'll need to download some libraries. So far I found [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/exchange-ssis-task-import-2008.rst). Will it do the trick? If not, do you know any other way to achieve what I want using SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the default SSIS library doesn't have the components required to make a connection to an Exchange server. I found 2 third party libraries that allow you to do that:

- [CozyRoc](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/receive-mail-task)
- [CData](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/exchange-ssis-task-import-2008.rst)

Both of them are paid but also have free testing versions.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use the [Microsoft Exchange Webservices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) (=EWS) to download and [work with all kind of attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726693(v=exchg.150).aspx) (here is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726695(v=exchg.150).aspx)).

However as this is a API you need to build some kind of middleware between MS Exchange and your SQL Server based on the [EWS API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx). It could be something like:

```
//TODO: Replace these with your values
NetworkCredential exchangeAccessAccount = new NetworkCredential(@"UserName", @"Password", @"Domain");
Uri OutlookWebAccessUri = new Uri(@"[[Outlook Web Access Url]]/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
DateTime CalanderStart = new DateTime();
DateTime CalanderEnd = new DateTime();
int MaxItemsToReturn = 99999;

try
{
    #region create service binding

    // Create the service binding.
    ExchangeService esb = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    esb.Credentials = exchangeAccessAccount;
    esb.Url = OutlookWebAccessUri;
    esb.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, Variables.UserDomainID.ToString());

    #endregion

    #region create CalendarView

    CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(CalanderStart, CalanderEnd, MaxItemsToReturn);
    calendarView.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;

    #endregion

    #region retrieve responce

    // Do the EWS Call...
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> findItemResponse = esb.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendarView);

    if (findItemResponse == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    #endregion

    #region load atendee data

    //get additional properties for each item returned by view, do this as view cannot return a lot of useful stuff like attendees
    ServiceResponseCollection<ServiceResponse> addProperties = 
                esb.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in findItemResponse select item,
                new PropertySet(
                        BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                        AppointmentSchema.Resources,
                        AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees,
                        AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees,
                        AppointmentSchema.Subject,
                        AppointmentSchema.Start,
                        AppointmentSchema.End,
                        AppointmentSchema.IsCancelled
                        ));

    List<Appointment> additionalProperties = new List<Appointment>(addProperties.Count);

    if (addProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (ServiceResponse currentResponce in addProperties)
        {
           additionalProperties.Add(((Appointment)((GetItemResponse)currentResponce).Item));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region process appts

    Appointment currentAppointmentAddProps = null;

    foreach (Appointment currentAppointment in findItemResponse)
    {
        #region find additional properties for current Appointment

        currentAppointmentAddProps = additionalProperties.Find(delegate(Appointment arg)
              { return arg.Id == currentAppointment.Id; });

        #endregion

        //add data to output here
       OutputRecordSetBuffer.ActualEndDate = currentAppointmentAddProps.End;

    }

    #endregion
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

(more infos [here](https://stuarthough.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/reading-appointments-from-exchange-in-ssis/))